# jquery has class and hover

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I tried the code:

```
$('a').hasClass('button-hello').hover(function() { alert('ffs'); });
```

I have tried this, without success. I am trying to trigger hover on any A link that has button-hello in the class.

Comment: `hasClass` returns a Boolean, not a jQuery object.

Comment: RTFD: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass

Answer (score 3):

The following code:

```
$('a.button-hello').hover(function() { alert('ffs'); });
```

Will work on the following elements:

```
<a href="#" class="button-hello">A1</a>
<a href="#" class="button-hello a">A2</a>
<a href="#" class="button-hello a b">A3</a>
<a href="#" class="button-hello a b c">A4</a>
```

[JsFiddle.net Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3kNTf/)

Comment: that works if the class = button-hello, i need it to work when the class contains 'button-hello' as there are muliple classes..

Comment: Still works, that how CSS/jQuery works.  Posted updated example.

Comment: @brianwilson Might want to read up on how selectors actually work. Eric is 100% correct.

Comment: in case you didnt understand my additional comment, this will not work if the class includes OTHER classes. eg class='btn button-hello' you might want to read peoples comments more clearly yourself before  telling people they need to 'read up'.

Comment: @brianwilson Sorry you are wrong. If you even took a minute to look at my example, you'd see it works.